# Is there a way to prevent labels from being on top of everything else?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm having a problem in `QGIS 1.7.4`. The labels I have produced for one layer are overlapping an entirely different layer that has a higher precedence. This should not happen. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

And just to make sure my question was clear, I'm asking if there is a way to prevent labels from being on top of everything else regardless of layer order

Comment: Could you indicate if you are using the labeling engine accessible through the Layer Properties (the old labeling engine) or the labeling accessible through the Layer Menu (the new labeling engine). At this time, QGIS has two labeling engines. These will as I understand be consolidated for version 2.0.

Comment: Yep, I was using the old one in the layer properties. Thanks for the heads up, I will see if the new engine helps me out!

Answer (score 1):

In my quick testing, layer labels do not overlap using the new engine accessible from the Layer menu (Layer -> Labeling).