# Preventing layer's labels from overlapping other layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am using QGIS 2.14 and trying to move labels from one layer (="polygon") in order to not overlap features from another layer (=purple "point"):

[image]

I tried to move the labels with the Placement option in the Label tab properties-but with no success. I also read a lot of questions in this subject but I didn't understand how can I do it ([Is there a way to prevent labels from being on top of everything else?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25973/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-labels-from-being-on-top-of-everything-else?rq=1) etc).

I am seeking for a similar answer as in ArcGIS, see this answer: [How to prevent labels from one layer from overlapping features in another layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93364/how-to-prevent-labels-from-one-layer-from-overlapping-features-in-another-layer)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using QGIS 2.16, so it's possible this is a new feature, but I don't think so. Open the Labels tab for the **point layer** and select the "Blocking" option from the menu at the top. It should block any labels from being placed on top of this layer. [image]

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.10. When I selected Blocking for the point layer, it did *not* prevent labels from another layer from overlapping the points, but it *did* prevent the point labels from showing up at all. So this answer made things worse for me.